# a<b is not identified by html

Tags: html, mathjax

Here is my code in the html file:

```
<li>For any $0 \leq s < t$, the random variable $B_t - B_s$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $t-s$, i.e., for any $a<b$, </li>

It's supposed to appear a<b in the end.
```

However, when I opened the html in the Chrome, I found that the part after a is missing. It might be that the Chrome identify `<b` as a node in the website. Any thoughts to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` in HTML represents a tag. If you want to make sure that less than or greater than symbols appear you should use entities.

Example:

Use `&lt;` instead of `<`

Use `&gt;` instead of `>`

Answer (score 1):

The `<` character is reserved in HTML for starting tags, so what follows is interpretted as a tag; as you did earlier, you can use `$\leq$` instead.

Comment: `\leq` represents *non-HTML source markup* (TeX-ish?) but it will not be *rendered* as a `<` in an HTML document. The OP probably wishes the `<` to be rendered as such to represent the (non-HTML source) markup graphically.

Comment: Since there was no complaint about its earlier use within `$`'s, I assumed it would work here as well.